# If a checkbox is checked, REQUIRE a text field to be filled in. Text field is FAILING: always required regardless of checkbox status

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, textfield, required

I have a group of 3 check boxes. If the one labelled as "mouthpiece" is checked, then the text field labelled mpTxt must NOT be left blank for the form to validate. Currently, the form is requiring the mpTxt field to be filled regardless of what is checked.

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-6">
    <b><u>Interface </u></b><br>
    <input id="F429_interfaceTrachCkBx" class="F429_backupV" name="F429_interfaceTrachCkBx" 
type="checkbox">
    Trach 
    <input id="F429_interfaceMaskCkBx" class="F429_backupV" name="F429_interfaceMaskCkBx" 
type="checkbox">
    Mask 
    <input id="mouthpiece" class="F429_backupV" name="F429_interfaceMouthpieceCkBx" type="checkbox">
    Mouthpiece <br>
</div>

 Mouthpiece Ventilation (MPV) Settings 
 <input id="mpTxt" class="F429_mpvSetting" name="F429_mpvSetting" type="text">
```

JavaScript:

```
//REQUIRE MPV TEXT IF CKBX CHECKED

var checkBox = document.querySelector('input[id="mouthpiece"]');
var textInput = document.querySelector('input[id="mpTxt"]');

function toggleRequired() {

if (textInput.hasAttribute('required') !== true) {
    textInput.setAttribute('required','required');
}

else {
    textInput.removeAttribute('required');  
}
}

checkBox.addEventListener('change',toggleRequired,false);
```

Comment: I tried pasting your code in a jsfiddle and it's working as expected. When I check the mouthpiece checkbox, the text field becomes required:

https://jsfiddle.net/nxua2to0/

Comment: interesting. Something in my other javascript must be interfering. Thanks. Will update when I find the fix.

Comment: SOLVED: This was due to Internet Explorer storing cookies. All other browsers work.

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to cookies being stored in Internet Explorer browser.